# Using XMLFilterImpl getting the characters values in the XML

Tags: xml-parsing

I have written code for reading one xml and filter for unwanted tags and write a new xml.I am able to filter the wanted Tags with values but not able to filter the unwanted tags values.

Code :

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    XMLReader xr = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equals("COLLECTION") || qName.equals("Transaction") || qName.equals("CreatedDate")
                   ) {

                super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
            }
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equals("COLLECTION") || qName.equals("Transaction") || qName.equals("CreatedDate")){

                super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
            }
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {


                super.characters(ch, start, length);



        }
    };
    Source src = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource("/xml"));
    Result res = new StreamResult(System.out);

    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, res);

}
```